# Google Sheets solution

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns, Column A has values that increment by 10 and column b has the incrementation difference AKA...

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 125 | 135 | 5 |
| 135 | 145 | 6 |
| 145 | 155 | 7 |

Ext... (There are hundreds of rows with these incrementing values)

I also have a value that is placed in an arbitrary place such as "137" we'll call it D1

I need to cycle through the columns some how and find out...

If D1 is => 135 and less than 145 and if so, place the value of column C in another cell AKA(E1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If D1 is => 135 and less than 145 and if so, place the value of column C in another cell AKA(E1).

Try the following in E1:

```
=arrayformula(if(isbetween(D1:D,135,145,1,0),C1:C,))
```

**EDIT**

> i need to cycle through columns A and B and find where my D1 number fits and output the corresponding C value to E1

Try:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(D1:D,{A1:A,C1:C},2))
```